# $C_{c}(X)$ is complete implies $X$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question, banach-algebras

If $X$ locally compact Hausdorff space. Then  $C_{c}(X)$ is complete implies $X$ is compact.

I know that $C_{c}(X)$ dense in $C_{0}(X)$. So in that case  $C_{c}(X)=C_{0}(X)$. I know only Tiez extension theorem on locally compact Hausdorff space and vary basic knowledge of Banach Algebra.